# how would someone add view(s) when the menu appears as a consequence of the user pressing the menu button in android?

Tags: android

In the default Android web browser, when the user clicks the 'menu' button, the menu icons slide up from the bottom and the address bar from top.  How would someone implement something similar.  More specifically, how would anyone add view(s) when the menu appears as a consequence of the user pressing the menu button?

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `onKeyDown`function, add your own code to an `if` with the menu-button as argument, and trigger the super's `onKeyDown` function afterwards (as in, always trigger that function, but only trigger your code when the key is 'menu')

Comment: The problem with this is that, once the user displays the menu and my custom views also appears, the user will have to click the added view(s) twice to interact with them.  Once to discard the menu, and the other to interact with the newly created view, which is not how it works in the browser.  Also, pressing the back menu when the menu is displayed will not discard the newly created view(s).

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the onKeyDown method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // Add Views here
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

If you do not want the menu to appear like normal, then return true after `// Add Views here` to signify you have handled the key press.

As far as adding Views, you can use the LayoutInflater for layouts already defined in XML:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.someviewgroup);

// Add an inflated view directly to a ViewGroup
inflater.inflate(R.layout.whateverlayout, viewGroup);

// Or inflate a view and then add it to a ViewGroup later
View someInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whateverlayout, null);
viewGroup.addView(someInflatedView);
```

Or you can create the View with code and add it:

```
ImageView someImageView = new ImageView(this);
someImageView.setImageDrawable(someDrawable);
someImageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.someviewgroup);
viewGroup.addView(someImageView);
```

Comment: thanks, but the comment I added to the previous answer still holds true.  The menu will be on top of everything else, and users will still have to discard it by clicking back or touching outside the menu area.  Also, pressing the back button will not discard the newly created views.

Comment: Take a look at the browser source, in particular mFakeTitleBar: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Browser.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/browser/BrowserActivity.java;h=0a3fec9a4336f1db4e3ae463c1ba061c59edff24;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 0):

You can use onPepareOptionsMenu. It gets called just before the menu is displayed.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29